# Figure on the left and some complex comments on the right

Tags: floats

As the title described, I would like to put a figure on the left and make some complex comments parallelly on the right. I write some code, but I feel the code is not "clean" . Sometimes works but sometimes with an error notice. I appreciate someone could help me to give out a clean and nice code, then I can use it for many other similar jobs.

One practical example is as following (I would like to have something shown by the picture) [image]

And the current bad written Latex code with error message as follow:

```
\begin{SCfigure}[\sidecaptionrelwidth][h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{E:/.../Sample.jpg}
\caption{$\boxed{
\varphi(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot exp (-\frac{y^2}{2})
}$
\\ 
Density of $N(0,1)$ with $y=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$}
\end{SCfigure}
```

The Error Message:

[image]

Comment: Please always post complete documents that show the problem. A non standard command appears to be complaining about a blank line (`\par`) in the document but your fragment doesn't have a blank line and gives no indication where `SCfigure` or `\boxed` are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method to realize something like this is to use two adjacent minipages.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{mathtools,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        no marks,
        smooth,
        axis lines=middle,
        enlargelimits=true,
        domain=-3:3,
        width=\linewidth,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$f(x)$,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        ]
        \addplot {1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)};
        \draw[<->] (axis cs:-1,0.25) -- node[above,pos=0.25] {1} node[above,pos=0.75] {1} (axis cs:1,0.25);
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}
  \quad
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\linewidth}
    \[ \boxed{f(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right)} \]
    Density of $N(0,1)$ with $y=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Gaussian distributon}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]